# Recursive function result as array not showing desired result

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, recursion, codeigniter-2

I have a controller `ajax` where the two functions exists :

```
  function customer_comission()
  {
            ---------------------------
            ---------------------------
        $arr = $this->show_parent_id( $child_node );

        var_dump($arr);
            ----------------------------
            ---------------
  }

function show_parent_id( $cust_id ){

    if( $cust_id > 2 ):
        $cust_id2 = $this->comission_model->show_parent_id( $cust_id );
        $cust_array[] = $cust_id2;
        //echo $this->show_parent_id( $cust_id2 ); 
         $this->show_parent_id( $cust_id2 );  
    endif;

    return $cust_array; // <-- This is Line 38
}
```

So what I want to display is the array of `parent_id`'s for the `$cust_id` hierarchy. The `echo $this->show_parent_id( $cust_id2 );`   prints the desired results, but when I tried to add them in an array, and then I got the error is showing :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: cust_array
>
> Filename: controllers/ajax.php
>
> Line Number: 38

Comment: Obviously, when `$cust_id<=2`, `$cust_array` is never defined. Either give it a default value beforehand, or provide an `else` branch defining it. Apart from that, why `$this->comission_model->show_parent_id( $cust_id )`? Wouldn't `$this->show_parent_id( $cust_id )` suffice?

Comment: `$this->comission_model->show_parent_id( $cust_id )` returns the `parent_id` from database.

Comment: I was referring to the `comission_model->` part being maybe redundant?

Answer (score 1):

That is because whenever `$cust_id <= 2` then `$cust_array` variable falls undefined.So just initialize it befor the if condition like this

```
function show_parent_id( $cust_id ){
    $cust_array = array();
    if( $cust_id > 2 ){
        $cust_id2 = $this->comission_model->show_parent_id( $cust_id );
        $cust_array[] = $cust_id2;
        //echo $this->show_parent_id( $cust_id2 ); 
         $this->show_parent_id( $cust_id2 );  
    }

    return $cust_array; // <-- This is Line 38
}
```

Comment: It returns `parent_id` of `$cust_id` passed. The `parent id` s for the results are not in the array